# How to debug "not a valid selector" without access to the offending browser page

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, selectors-api

I made a TamperScript at work (in Chrome) that gathers a list of elements from a webpage. The script is used by many people without errors. But on one person's workstation it fails with the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '(list of selectors)' is not a valid selector.
```

(list of selectors) above is a long list of selectors; but the same list works fine, not just on my machine, but on every one else's (on the exact same webpage).

The offending workstation is remote and I don't have access to it; how can I debug this? starting with reproducing the error?

... and where could the error come from? Is it possible that another extension causes it?

Edit: selector list:

```
h1, h2, h3, p-inputswitch, p-multiselect, p-multiselect-items-wrapper, input, button, a[routerlink], a.alert-item, a.btn-primary, th, label:has(+select),  div.switch-list-header, .filters-tags
```

Comment: If we're debugging a broken selector, then the 'list of selectors' is the part we really need to see. Also, if it's working for most people but not for one, what browser si this person using?

Comment: Ok, added list of selectors; however this is working fine for everyone except that one person; everyone uses the same version of Chrome which is updated by the company (everyone is updated at the same time); so it should really be absolutely the same environment; the only difference I can think of is other extensions installed...?

Comment: Have you asked the user of that remote workstation, if the problem persists when they disable all their extensions, resp. test in private mode? Some ad-blocker would probably be the best "suspect", although I can't spot anything in your selector that would "typically" trigger those (words/texts such as `ad`, or `___x___` indicating typical ad image formats, ...)

Comment: You could try and send the user to a test page, that tries all these selectors one after the other, and see which particular one it fails on then. That might help narrow it down at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the user had a very old version of Chrome, that for some reason didn't update normally. It was the only case out of 60+ so nobody thought about verifying this.

Also, we found that the error wasn't generated by Chrome directly but by an Angular polyfill (which instantiated itself for only that user, because they were using that old Chrome version).

Edit, I did code this to help with troubleshooting, if it can help someone (as per @CBroe comment)

```
<html>
<head><title>selector tester</title></head>
<body>
    <textarea id="sels" style="width:40em; height:10em;">h1, h2, h3, p-inputswitch, p-multiselect!=1</textarea>
    <br/>
    <button id="tester" style="margin-top: 0.8em;">testit</button>
    <script>
        const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
        const selectors = $("#sels").innerHTML.split(",").map(s => s.trim());
        $("#tester").addEventListener("click", e => {
            selectors.forEach(sel => console.log(sel, $(sel)));
            });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```